# A question edited while the close dialog is open fails to refresh properly

Tags: bug, edits, user-interface, live-refresh, close-dialog

I was closing a question, and while I had the close dialog open an edit was made to the question – I saw the usual "this post has been edited" banner appear in the background. When I completed closing the question, the question body was replaced with a blank space:

[image: screenshot of the described problem]